# How is the Vader 'compound' polarity score calculated in Python NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, vader

I'm using the Vader SentimentAnalyzer to obtain the polarity scores. I used the probability scores for positive/negative/neutral before, but I just realized the "compound" score, ranging from -1 (most neg) to 1 (most pos) would provide a single measure of polarity. I wonder how the "compound" score computed. Is that calculated from the [pos, neu, neg] vector?

Comment: The code is at: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sentiment/vader.py

Answer (score 98):

The VADER algorithm outputs sentiment scores to 4 classes of sentiments https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sentiment/vader.py#L441:

- `neg`: Negative
- `neu`: Neutral
- `pos`: Positive
- `compound`: Compound (i.e. aggregated score)

Let's walk through the code, the first instance of compound is at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sentiment/vader.py#L421, where it computes:

```
compound = normalize(sum_s)
```

The `normalize()` function is defined as such at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sentiment/vader.py#L107:

```
def normalize(score, alpha=15):
    """
    Normalize the score to be between -1 and 1 using an alpha that
    approximates the max expected value
    """
    norm_score = score/math.sqrt((score*score) + alpha)
    return norm_score
```

So there's a hyper-parameter `alpha`.

As for the `sum_s`, it is a sum of the sentiment arguments passed to the `score_valence()` function https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sentiment/vader.py#L413

And if we trace back this `sentiment` argument, we see that it's computed when calling the `polarity_scores()` function at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sentiment/vader.py#L217:

```
def polarity_scores(self, text):
    """
    Return a float for sentiment strength based on the input text.
    Positive values are positive valence, negative value are negative
    valence.
    """
    sentitext = SentiText(text)
    #text, words_and_emoticons, is_cap_diff = self.preprocess(text)

    sentiments = []
    words_and_emoticons = sentitext.words_and_emoticons
    for item in words_and_emoticons:
        valence = 0
        i = words_and_emoticons.index(item)
        if (i < len(words_and_emoticons) - 1 and item.lower() == "kind" and \
            words_and_emoticons[i+1].lower() == "of") or \
            item.lower() in BOOSTER_DICT:
            sentiments.append(valence)
            continue

        sentiments = self.sentiment_valence(valence, sentitext, item, i, sentiments)

    sentiments = self._but_check(words_and_emoticons, sentiments)
```

Looking at the `polarity_scores` function, what it's doing is to iterate through the whole SentiText lexicon and checks with the rule-based `sentiment_valence()` function to assign the valence score to the sentiment https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sentiment/vader.py#L243, see Section 2.1.1 of http://comp.social.gatech.edu/papers/icwsm14.vader.hutto.pdf

So going back to the compound score, we see that:

- the `compound` score is a normalized score of `sum_s` and
- `sum_s` is the sum of valence computed based on some heuristics and a sentiment lexicon (aka. Sentiment Intensity) and
- the normalized score is simply the `sum_s` divided by its square plus an alpha parameter that increases the denominator of the normalization function.

---

**Is that calculated from the [pos, neu, neg] vector?**

Not really =)

If we take a look at the `score_valence` function https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sentiment/vader.py#L411, we see that the compound score is computed with the `sum_s` before the pos, neg and neu scores are computed using `_sift_sentiment_scores()` that computes the invidiual pos, neg and neu scores using the raw scores from `sentiment_valence()` without the sum.

---

If we take a look at this `alpha` mathemagic, it seems the output of the normalization is rather unstable (if left unconstrained), depending on the value of `alpha`:

`alpha=0`:

[image]

`alpha=15`:

[image]

`alpha=50000`:

[image]

`alpha=0.001`:

[image]

It gets funky when it's negative:

`alpha=-10`:

[image]

`alpha=-1,000,000`:

[image]

`alpha=-1,000,000,000`:

[image]

Comment: Very good explanation, seems like you're missing the sqrt part in the graphs & equations

Comment: Hi Alvas, could I ask you to take a look at the question I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707282/example-of-nltks-vader-scoring-text

Comment: I think the functions in plots are missing a square root. The function is `score/math.sqrt(score*score+alpha)`, but you are plotting `score/(score*score+alpha)`. Otherwise, good analysis!

Answer (score 9):

"About the Scoring" section at the [github repo](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment) has a description.